# Binding offsets of figure and tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, margins

I am trying to get an image to start a certain distance from left of a page (2 cm). When I use tikzpicture, and tikzpicture inside the figure environment, I get different offsets from the left hand side.

Code and result as follows, the measurements are done in adobe.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,footskip=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   {\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image}}
\end{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node {\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{figure}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node {\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image}};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Have I got my preamble set up correctly for this?

And how can I force both instances of tikzpicture to keep my desired offsets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two problems here:

- By default each node in `tikz` has some padding around it. You can turn this off by setting both `inner sep` and `outer sep` to `0`.
- You need to turn off paragraph indentation before a `tikzpicture` environment by putting `\noindent` before the environment. When you are inside a `figure` environment it is not necessary to do this.

Here's a patch of your MWE that fixes both of these problems:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,footskip=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image}
\end{figure}

 \noindent% stop paragraph indentation
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0] {\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{figure}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[inner sep=0, outer sep=0]{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This produces the desired result:

[image]

Of course, you could make it so that no node as any spacing around it with

```
\tikzset{node/.style={style={inner sep=0, outer sep=0}}}
```

and then use `\node{\includegraphics...}`. Or, you could define a style for nodes without separation with

```
\tikzset{tight/.style={inner sep=0, outer sep=0}}
```

and then use `\node[tight]{\includegraphics...}`.

You can also turn off paragraph indentation "globally" with `\parindent=0pt`.